# how to pass array of strings into a function and use it in "IN" statement in SQL

Tags: function, postgresql-9.5

It may be simple but somehow, I still don't get it correct.
How to pass array of strings into a function and use it in "IN" statement in SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test_function(array_para text)
RETURNS TABLE (data text) 
AS $$
begin
    
    return query select col1 from my_table where my_table.col2 in(array_para)
END 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and how can I call it?
may be --

```
select test_function('''ABC'', ''MITT''')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the parameter as and array, e.g. `text[]`. You also don't need PL/pgSQL for that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test_function(array_para text[])
RETURNS TABLE (data text) 
AS $$
  select col1 
  from my_table 
  where my_table.col2 = any (array_para)
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then call it with:

```
select *
from test_function(array['ABC', 'MITT']);
```

---

Another option is to use a `variadic` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test_function(variadic array_para text[])
RETURNS TABLE (data text) 
AS $$
  select col1 
  from my_table 
  where my_table.col2 = any (array_para)
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then you can call it with:

```
select *
from test_function('ABC', 'MITT', 'DEF');
```